# Windows 8 Desktop app and Windows 8 Store app

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, windows-8

I'm starting to develop Windows 8 app with Visual Studio 2013 and I'm not sure which are the different betweens a desktop app with a store app.

Using Visual Studio 2013, how can I develop a W8 desktop app? and a store app?

My app is going to use InApp purchase. Can I use it on a Windows 8 Desktop app?

I'm going to use C#. A Windows 8 desktop app is a WPF app?

On a WPF app, can I use common gestures like tap, pinch, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Desktop apps on Windows 8 are everything you know about apps from Windows 7. Furthermore, Windows 8 brings a new  type of apps - the `Windows Store Apps` (WinRT apps) which are the ones run on fullscreen or snapped (term bit forced on 8.1) which use the WinRT API (XAML based, similar to WPF, brings new things, but doesn't have all WPF can offer; also you can use HTML + JavaScript for WinRT Apps)

Now, in VS 2013, if you want to create a desktop app - choose the templates related to WinForms or WPF (just like before). To create the Windows Store Apps, chose `Windows Store`section of Templates, and then select your app template (Grid App, Blank App etc)

A desktop app will respond to touch gestures on a touch-screen based device because it will replace the cursor actions from the desktop. But for specialized gestures, I'd suggest the Windows Store Apps.

Summarized : Desktop Apps - everything is the same, just like Windows 7.
Windows 8 Apps - the `Windows Store` apps developed with the WinRT API.

Comment: To read more about Windows 8 apps, try searching using the WinRT term. So search after 'WinRT Apps'